# Animating android view in Z direction (from back to forward and vice versa)

Tags: android, animation, properties, coordinate

Good day.I have done lots of google searches and ofcourse analyzed lots of cods of animation properties inside android studio but could not find any usable information about animating the view in Z direction.The 3D effect animation is made by rotation on degrees,but what if i want an button to go back in Z direction,and another button to come forward in z Direction.An occasionally example,not so good but still example,can be taken from Android post-lollipop devices,where the Task Manager items are sorted in Z direction (in most of devices but not all).So my question is how can i achieve that with android default animation properties?If not,is there any library to achieve what i ask?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [FlipImageView](https://github.com/castorflex/FlipImageView) library. May be using it is a fastest way to do what you want.

Comment: unfortunatally i have seen this,so yeah basically this is simply rotating,no controls over z axis at all

Comment: I think you can imitate z axis movement with changed alpha and size of control.

Comment: interesting,and how that can be achieved though?

Comment: it is pathetic not to give control over Z axis,because it is definataly android have that axis,but why in world we out of it i cant understand

Comment: Add animation set to button with alpha (from 0 to 1) and scale (from 75% to 100%) and another animation set to second button alpha (from 1 to 0) and scale (from 100% to 75%)